# minimum value of $(8a^2+b^2+c^2)\cdot (a^{-1}+b^{-1}+c^{-1})^2$

Tags: inequality

> If $a,b,c>0.$ Then minimum value of
>
> $(8a^2+b^2+c^2)\cdot (a^{-1}+b^{-1}+c^{-1})^2$

Try: Arithmetic geometric inequality

$8a^2+b^2+c^2\geq 3\cdot 2\sqrt{2}(abc)^{1/3}$

and $(a^{-1}+b^{-1}+c^{-1})\geq 3(abc)^{-1/3}$

so $(8a^2+b^2+c^2)\cdot (a^{-1}+b^{-1}+c^{-1})^2\geq 18\sqrt{2}(abc)^{-1/3}$

could some help me to solve it.  answer is $64$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hint:* Apply $AM \ge GM$ not to $8a^2 + b^2 + c^2$, but to
$$
 (2a)^2 + (2a)^2 + b^2 + c^2
$$
and $HM \le GM$ not to $a^{-1}+b^{-1}+c^{-1}$, but to
$$
\frac{1}{2a} + \frac{1}{2a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}
$$

The “partitions” are chosen in such a way that equality can hold *simultaneously* in both estimates, in this case when $2a=b=c$.

One can also use the relationships between [generalized means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean), here “harmonic mean $\le$ quadratic mean”:
$$
\frac{4}{\frac{1}{2a} + \frac{1}{2a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}}
\le \sqrt{\frac{(2a)^2 + (2a)^2 + b^2 + c^2}{4}}
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Another way is to consider [Hölder's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Counting_measure)

$$(8a^2+b^2+c^2)(a^{-1}+b^{-1}+c^{-1})^2 \geqslant (2+1+1)^3$$

Equality is possible when $8a^3=b^3=c^3=1$ (why?), so this is the minimum.

Comment: Yes! – Why did I not think of that?

Comment: Essentially convexity - whether AM-GM-HM or Hölder or Jensen... so not very different after all.

Comment: Yes, but this approach works with arbitrary coefficients and does not require to  find a suitable partition of the sums.